# Передача данных с помощью протокола на второй контроллер

Tags: ios, swift, коллекции, протоколы, protocol

UPD. Добавил ссылку на прокет на гугл диск

**[макет проекта на гугл диске](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3iDHUwQgahAeGVOOTdkcVpnVWM/view?usp=sharing)**

Имею два **viewController**. Сразу напишу что пока что не очень хорошо знаком с протоколами. Но другого способа передать данные при помощи моего кода я не нашел.

**viewController1** имеет в себе **collectionCell** внутри **collectionCell**. **Первый collectionCell** нужен для создания таблицы (знаю что можно и tableView использовать, но пока так, разницы особой нету), **второй collectionCell** для листания изображений.

**viewController2** должен принимать на себя массив изображений который хранится в каждом из изображений из **viewController1** для листания.

Суть в том что надо передать данные на **viewController2** в **collectionCell** при нажатии на ячейку **collectionCell** из **viewController1**. Так же немного не понимаю как правильно передавать данные с помощью **String** или с помощью **class Model**(**class Model** я создал для подгрузки изображений из **firebase**)? Но больше склоняюсь что надо передавать данные с помощью **class Model**.

Мой код:

**viewController1**:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, detailSegue2 {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    var image: [Model] = []

    var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "Студии2")

        ref.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            var newImage: [Model] = []

            for imageSnap in snapshot.children {
                let imageObj = Model(snapshot: imageSnap as! FIRDataSnapshot)
                newImage.append(imageObj)
            }
            self.image = newImage
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        })
    }

    func prepare(image: Model) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: image)
    }
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let dvc = segue.destination as! ViewController2
        dvc.photo = sender as? Model
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return image.count

    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell11
//        cell.delegate = self
        cell.delegate2 = self
        cell.imagess = [image[indexPath.item].image,
                        image[indexPath.item].image2] // загружаем изображение в созданную ранее ячейку

        return cell
    }
}
```

**collectionCell1** из **viewController1**:

```
class CollectionViewCell11: UICollectionViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

//    var delegate: detalSegue!
    var delegate2: detailSegue2?

    var imagess: [String] = []
    var photos: [Model] = []

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return imagess.count
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell12
        cell.imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: imagess[indexPath.item])) // создается ячейка чтобы позже в нее поместить изображение
        return cell
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
//        delegate?.preform(image: imagess[indexPath.item])
        if let qwert = photos[indexPath.item] {
            delegate2?.prepare(image: qwert)
        }
    }
}
```

**viewController2**:

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

//    var photo: [String] = []
//    
//    override func viewDidLoad() {
//        super.viewDidLoad()
//
//    }
//    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
//        return photo.count
//    }
//    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
//        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell2
//        cell.imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: photo[indexPath.item]))
//        return cell
//    }
    var photo: Model?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier:     "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell2
        cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: (photo?.image)!)
        return cell
    }
}
```

**class Model**:

```
class Model {
    var image: String
    var image2: String
    var images: [String] = []
    var images2: [String] = []
    var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!

    init(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) {
        ref = snapshot.ref
        let value = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary
        let snap = value["hall1"] as? NSDictionary
        let snap2 = value["hall2"] as? NSDictionary
        image = snap?["qwerty"] as? String ?? ""
        image2 = snap2?["qwerty"] as? String ?? ""
        if let post1 = snap as? [String: AnyObject] {
            for (_, value) in post1["images"] as! [String: AnyObject] {
                self.images.append(value as! String)
            }
        }
        if let post1 = snap2 as? [String: AnyObject] {
            for (_, value) in post1["images"] as! [String: AnyObject] {
                self.images2.append(value as! String)
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

и **протокол** (в нем тоже есть небольшие сомнения, но вроде бы он правильный):

```
protocol detailSegue2 {
    func prepare(image: Model)
}
```

Comment: Зачем протокол для передачи на второй контроллер? Используйте prepare(for:sender:)

Comment: С использованием prepare я могу передать массив только первого изображения из коллекции, а если в коллекции два и более изображений и при клике на вторую ячейку ничего не передаётся(( Если можно избежать протокола я буду рад)) но подскажите как прописать код?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы на вашем месте отказался от:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let dvc = segue.destination as! ViewController2
    dvc.photo = sender as? Model
}
```

Убрал бы все связи в сториборде.

Удалил бы с вашего `CollectionViewCell11` все `delegate`, и `datasource`.

Перешел бы во `ViewController1`

и в методе:

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let vc2 = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController2") as! ViewController2
        //обязательно в сториборде в пункте identify дайте название ViewController2

        vc2.photo = photos[indexPath.row] 
        //тут уже на ваше усмотрение, в зависимости какая структура у вашего массива и что именно вам надо передовать.
        let backItem = UIBarButtonItem()
        backItem.title = ""
        navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backItem
        //это для того чтобы во vc2 вместо стрелки со словом "Назад" была просто стрелка.
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        //так реализовывается переход
    }
```

Таким простым способом вы можете передавать данные с одного контроллера на другой. И не надо юзать во первых протокол, а во вторых `prepare`. Так же не засорять сториборд связями.

Comment: Я может что-то не понимаю, но если я удалю в **CollectionViewCell11** все **delegate** и **datasource** то у меня не будут отображаться изображения которые я подгружаю в ячейки в **ViewController1**

Comment: @ДмитрийДеникаев Да я упустил что у тебя в саму ячейку ты запихал UICollectionView. Это печально конечно, ну ты можешь мою логику перенести в ячейку.

Comment: Я попробую как до компа доберусь, но по другому я не знаю как создать листание изображений

Comment: @ДмитрийДеникаев Если у тебя есть макет, по которому ты работаешь, можешь его скинуть, и мы тут подскажем как его лучше реализовать.

Comment: залил на гугл диск, на гитхаб почему то не хочет заливаться. Отпишу сюда и обновил вопрос ссылкой на гугл диск. Если проблемно скачивать с гугл диска, буду думать как на гитхаб залить. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3iDHUwQgahAeGVOOTdkcVpnVWM/view?usp=sharing